# JOIN tables based on 6 or 7 digits key in 1st table with 7 digits key in second table by using CASE and MAX function

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table 1:**

```
Id1 Data1
123123  David
123124  Jan
1231344 Juro
1234126 Marco
```

**Table 2:**

```
Id2 Data2
1231230 Info 1
1231231 Info 2
1231232 Info 3
1231240 Info 4
1231241 Info 5
1231242 Info 6
```

Each id from Table 1 can have 1 or more matches in Table 2 based on first 6 digits. 
For example 123123 from Table 1 matches  1231230, 1231231 and 1231232 in Table 2. 
I'm trying to create join to match maximum id2 from Table 2 based on id1 from Table 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working solution:

```
SELECT tb1.*,
       MAX(tb2.[id2]) as id2
FROM [dbo].[table1] tb1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[table2] tb2
    ON CASE 
        WHEN LEN(tb1.[id1]) = 7 and tb1.[id1] = tb2.[id2] THEN 1
        WHEN LEN(tb1.[id1]) = 6 and tb1.[id1] = SUBSTRING(tb2.[id2],1,6) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END = 1
GROUP BY tb1.id1
      ,tb1.data1
ORDER BY tb1.id1 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just join using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT
    tb1.id1,
    tb1.data1
    MAX(tb2.[id2]) AS id2
FROM [dbo].[table1] tb1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[table2] tb2
    ON tb2.[id2] LIKE CONCAT(tb1.[id1], '%')
GROUP BY 
    tb1.id1,
    tb1.data1
ORDER BY
    tb1.id1 DESC;
```

This approach might still leave open the possibility of using an index on the second table.  In any case, it is slightly easier to read than your version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
Declare @t table (id1 varchar(50) , data1 varchar(50))

insert into @t values (123123,'David')
insert into @t values (123124,'Jan')
insert into @t values (1231344,'Juro')


Declare @t1 table (id2 varchar(50) , data2 varchar(50))

insert into @t1 values (1231230,'Info 1')
insert into @t1 values (1231231,'Info 2')
insert into @t1 values (1231232,'Info 3')

insert into @t1 values (1231240,'Info 4')
insert into @t1 values (1231241,'Info 5')
insert into @t1 values (1231242,'Info 6')

select * from @t  a JOIN @t1 B
on b.id2 like '%' + a.id1 + '%'
```